# Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am currently looking at building SaaS construction management tool.
What I was wondering is if I used laravel passport for the api token how can I assign roles to users For example:

SuperAdmin: Can create projects | Can create new users and assign roles to user.

Admin: Can view projects.

Because I would like to be able to hide elements on my front end based upon a users permissions.

For example if I did a traditional laravel app I could use entrust and use blade directives @role('admin') to show elements based on a users permission type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Policies and Gates: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Then it becomes as simple as

```
$user = Auth::guard('api');
if ($user->can('create', Post::class)) {
    // Do something
}
```

To hide/show stuff in the frontend, when you get the user, you get their permissions as well

```
$user = Auth::guard('api');
$user->isAdmin = $user->can('create', Post::class); //returns true or false
```

In your frontend you show/hide stuff with that. E.g: using angular

```
<li ng-if="vm.user.isAdmin">Admin</li>
```

Comment: Wow that is pretty simple. Thank you!  Just one other question. I am quite new to passport. Does a users permission get stored in a database so on the front end I could do a check in vue for if a user has permission?

Comment: Yes, passport has its migrations. So it saves a lot of stuff. But you can get user's permissions by simply checking their Policies. There are serveral different ways for that. You can see how I did that, assuming that ONLY admins can 'create' posts.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for the help! I was going down the angular route for the front end! Your help was immensely useful and will help me through my degree project thanks once again! 5*